# Can I add a drive to a existing zfs drive pool

Tags: zfs

I have 4 drives in a Zfs pool. I got 4 more drives that I want to add to the same "data" pool. I'm new to zfs and raid pools I was told that I could maybe use:

zpool add (pool name) /dev/(harddrive location)

Comment: A quick google search turned up https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/zfs-zpool.html  Look at section 19.3.2